# How to join all the lines together in a text file in python?

Tags: python

I have a file and when I open it, it prints out some paragraphs. I need to join these paragraphs together with a space to form one big body of text.

for e.g.

```
for data in open('file.txt'):
    print data
```

has an output like this:

```
Hello my name is blah. What is your name?
Hello your name is blah. What is my name?
```

How can the output be like this?:

```
Hello my name is blah. What is your name? Hello your name is blah. What is my name?
```

I've tried replacing the newlines with a space like so:

```
for data in open('file.txt'):
      updatedData = data.replace('\n',' ')
```

but that only gets rid of the empty lines, it doesn't join the paragraphs

and also tried joining like so:

```
for data in open('file.txt'):
    joinedData = " ".join(data)
```

but that separates each character with a space, while not getting rid of the paragraph format either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use `str.join`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```

`line.strip()` will remove all types of whitespaces from both ends of the line.
You can use `line.rstrip("\n")` to remove only the trailing `"\n"`.

If `file.txt` contains:

```
Hello my name is blah. What is your name?
Hello your name is blah. What is my name?
```

Then the output would be:

```
Hello my name is blah. What is your name? Hello your name is blah. What is my name?
```

Answer (score 8):

```
data = open('file.txt').read().replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looping over individual lines and it is the *`print`* statement that is adding newlines. The following would work:

```
for data in open('file.txt'):
    print data.rstrip('\n'),
```

With the trailing comma, `print` doesn't add a newline, and the `.rstrip()` call removes *just* the trailing newline from the line.

Alternatively, you need to pass all read and stripped lines to `' '.join()`, not each line itself. Strings in python are sequences to, so the string contained in line is interpreted as separate characters when passed on it's own to `' '.join()`.

The following code uses two new tricks; context managers and a list comprehension:

```
with open('file.txt') as inputfile:
    print ' '.join([line.rstrip('\n') for line in inputfile])
```

The `with` statement uses the file object as a context manager, meaning the file will be automatically closed when we are done with the block indented below the `with` statement. The `[.. for .. in ..]` syntax generates a list from the `inputfile` object where we turn each line into a version without a newline at the end.

Comment: Best answer here, especially the first one which avoids storing the entire file in memory

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's doing this in pandas, where you have all lines in a particular column, you can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# line is the name of the column containing all lines in df
df.line.to_string()
```