# Is there a way to read a text file as a an integer, and not a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a clicker game that saves the data in a text file and read it when the game starts, but when i write in the file with

```
self.file1 = open('money.txt', 'w')
self.file1.write(str(self.playerMoney)) 
self.file1.close()
```

It prints a list in my .txt file instead of the clear integer.
Here is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from time import sleep
from tkinter import messagebox


class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    file1 = open('money.txt', 'r')
    playerMoney = file1.read()
    file2 = open('autoFarmEarnings.txt', 'r')
    autoFarmEarnings = file2.read()
    file3 = open('autoFarmPrice.txt', 'r')
    priceAutoFarm = file3.read()
    file4 = open('earnings.txt', 'r')
    earnings = file4.read()
    file5 = open('upgradePrice.txt', 'r')
    upgradePrice = file5.read()
    

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Cliquer ici!"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
        self.moneybtn = tk.Button(self)
        self.moneybtn["text"] = ("Revenus : " + str(self.earnings) + "€.")
        self.moneybtn["command"] = self.money
        self.moneybtn.pack(side="top")
        self.moneybtn['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.upgrade = tk.Button(self)
        self.upgrade["text"] = ("Ammeliorer les revenus (" + str(self.upgradePrice) + "€.).")
        self.upgrade["command"] = self.upgradefunc
        self.upgrade.pack(side ="left")
        self.showMoney = tk.Button(self)
        self.showMoney['text'] = ('Argent : ' + str(self.playerMoney) + '€.')
        self.showMoney["state"] = "disabled"
        self.showMoney.pack(side = "right")

        self.autofarmbtn = tk.Button(self)
        self.autofarmbtn['text'] = 'Debloquer l\'autofarm. (1000€)'
        self.autofarmbtn['command'] = self.autofarmfunc
        self.autofarmbtn.pack(side = 'left')

        self.quit = tk.Button(self)
        self.quit['text'] = 'Sauvegarder et quitter.'
        self.quit['command'] = self.save_and_quit 
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


    def say_hi(self):
        print("Vous avez gagné " + str(self.earnings) + " euros.")
        self.playerMoney = self.playerMoney + self.earnings
        self.showMoney['text'] = ('Argent : ' + str(self.playerMoney) + '€.')
    
    def money(self):
        print(str(self.playerMoney))
    
    def upgradefunc(self):
        if (self.playerMoney) >= self.upgradePrice:
            print('Vous avez ammélioré vos revenus pour ' + str(self.upgradePrice) + ' €.')
            self.earnings = self.earnings + 10
            self.upgradePrice = self.upgradePrice + 20
            self.playerMoney = self.playerMoney - self.upgradePrice
            self.upgrade["text"] = ("Ammeliorer les revenus (" + str(self.upgradePrice) + "€.).")
            self.showMoney['text'] = ('Argent : ' + str(self.playerMoney) + '€.')
            self.moneybtn["text"] = ("Revenus : " + str(self.earnings) + "€.")
        elif self.playerMoney < self.upgradePrice:
            print('Vous n\'avez pas assez d\'argent pour acheter cette ammélioration!')

    def autofarm(self):
        while 1 < 2:
            sleep(1)
            self.playerMoney = self.playerMoney + self.autoFarmEarnings
    
    def autofarmfunc(self):
        print('Vous avez ammelioré l\'autofarm pour ' + str(self.priceAutoFarm) + '€.')
        self.priceAutoFarm = self.priceAutoFarm + 1000 * self.counter
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        self.autofarmbtn['text'] = ('Ammeliorer l\'autofarm. (' + str(self.priceAutoFarm) + '€.)')
        self.autoFarmEarnings = self.autoFarmEarnings + 2
        self.autofarm()
    
    def save_and_quit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Sauvegarder et quitter.", "Voulez vous sauvegarder et quitter?"):
            self.file1 = open('money.txt', 'w')
            self.file1.write(str(self.playerMoney)) 
            self.file1.close()

            self.file2 = open('autoFarmEarnings.txt', 'w')
            self.file2.write(str(self.autoFarmEarnings))
            self.file2.close()

            self.file3 = open('autoFarmPrice.txt', 'w')
            self.file3.write(str(self.priceAutoFarm))
            self.file3.close() 

            self.file4 = open('earnings.txt', 'w')
            self.file4.write(str(self.earnings))
            self.file4.close()
 
            self.file5 = open('upgradePrice.txt', 'w')
            self.file5.write(str(self.upgradePrice))
            self.file5.close()

            root.destroy()
            


    

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
root.title('Clicker')
app.mainloop()
```

And here is the screenshot of my game.

[image: Screenshot (Imgur)]

Comment: Why don't join all the lists in one string `''.join(lines)` [How to join all the lines together in a text file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393466/how-to-join-all-the-lines-together-in-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: Although why are you saving every digit in separate lines. It is a strange decision.

Comment: Please check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When you create your application, your program does this:

```
file1 = open('money.txt', 'r')
playerMoney = file1.read()
```

That sets `playerMoney` to a *string* containing the entire contents of `file1`. That is how `read()` works. If you want those contents to be interpreted as an integer then you have to do that yourself.

```
with open('money.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        playerMoney = int(line.strip())
        break
```

And it is clear that you have run the program several times and the contents of the file are completely messed up as a result. So after you have fixed the code, start again with a correct file.

Answer (score 0):

for and print every element for times.

it is a list. if you print it directly, it will be printed as a list.

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in range(len(a)):
    print a[x]`

Comment: Add your code from the comment directly to your answer so that it is better understandable that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the input to ints, before processing.
In your case, use an appropriate file format.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.read_state()
        self.master = master
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self, text="Cliquer ici!", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
        self.moneybtn = tk.Button(self, text=f"Revenus : {self.earnings}€.", command=self.money, state='disabled')
        self.moneybtn.pack(side="top")
        self.upgrade = tk.Button(self, text=f"Ammeliorer les revenus ({self.upgradePrice}€.).", command=self.upgradefunc)
        self.upgrade.pack(side ="left")
        self.showMoney = tk.Button(self, text=f'Argent : {self.playerMoney}€.', state="disabled")
        self.showMoney.pack(side = "right")
        self.autofarmbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Debloquer l'autofarm. (1000€)", command=self.autofarmfunc)
        self.autofarmbtn.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="Sauvegarder et quitter.", command=self.save_and_quit)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"Vous avez gagné {self.earnings} euros.")
        self.playerMoney += self.earnings
        self.showMoney['text'] = f'Argent : {self.playerMoney}€.'
    
    def money(self):
        print(self.playerMoney)
    
    def upgradefunc(self):
        if self.playerMoney >= self.upgradePrice:
            print(f'Vous avez ammélioré vos revenus pour {self.upgradePrice} €.')
            self.earnings += 10
            self.upgradePrice += 20
            self.playerMoney -= self.upgradePrice
            self.upgrade["text"] = f"Ammeliorer les revenus ({self.upgradePrice}€.)."
            self.showMoney['text'] = f'Argent : {self.playerMoney}€.'
            self.moneybtn["text"] = f"Revenus : {self.earnings}€."
        else:
            print("Vous n'avez pas assez d'argent pour acheter cette ammélioration!")

    def autofarm(self):
        self.playerMoney += self.autoFarmEarnings
        self.after(1000, self.autofarm)
    
    def autofarmfunc(self):
        print(f"Vous avez ammelioré l'autofarm pour {self.priceAutoFarm}€.")
        self.priceAutoFarm += 1000 * self.counter
        self.counter += 1
        self.autofarmbtn['text'] = f"Ammeliorer l'autofarm. ({self.priceAutoFarm}€.)"
        self.autoFarmEarnings += 2
        self.autofarm()
    
    def save_and_quit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Sauvegarder et quitter.", "Voulez vous sauvegarder et quitter?"):
            self.write_state()
            self.master.destroy()
            
        def write_state(self):
            with open('game.json', 'w') as file:
                json.dump({
                    "playerMoney": self.playerMoney,
                    "autoFarmEarnings": self.autoFarmEarnings,
                    "priceAutoFarm": self.priceAutoFarm,
                    "earnings": self.earnings,
                    "upgradePrice": self.upgradePrice,
                }, file)

        def read_state(self):
            with open('game.json') as file:
                state = json.load(file)
            self.playerMoney = state["playerMoney"]
            self.autoFarmEarnings = state["autoFarmEarnings"]
            self.priceAutoFarm = state["priceAutoFarm"]
            self.earnings = state["earnings"]
            self.upgradePrice = state["upgradePrice"]


def main():    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Clicker')
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
self.file1 = open('money.txt', 'w')
self.file1.write([int(a) for a in self.playerMoney ]) 
self.file1.close()
```

Just a simple List comprehension to write in the file as an integer
Then if you use this in Tkinter you can get values as integers